# Permissions Dialog default background dim color location

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, android-theme, android-styles

I would like my app's custom dialog dim color to match with the system's, through the backgroundDimAmount attribute in styles. How can I know what the default color is for that? Some posts have written it's based on the device, others that it is sdk platform-specific. If it is the latter, where are the individual attributes located?

Comment: The base default is [in the platform `res/values/themes.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#54), though, that can be changed through custom themes, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. What's strange is this: the backgroundDimAmount for the theme I use is listed as ".6", and looks similar on several devices. However if I put the same value in my custom dialog, it looks different on different devices.

Comment: If you use `?attr/backgroundDimAmount`, you will use whatever the theme's value is, even if that theme's value differs based on Android OS version, device manufacturer tweaks, etc. If your dialog's theme is inheriting from a stock theme, it should get that dim amount automatically.